# problem with turn ON a led with firebase ESP8266 (nodeMCU)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? The goal is to turn on and off the LED that is integrated in my ESP8266, it works perfectly with the example of blinking.

```html
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <Firebase.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>
#include <FirebaseError.h>
#include <FirebaseHttpClient.h>
#include <FirebaseObject.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "prueba2-1df50.firebaseio.com "
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "xTiqBi92rKrTV9GMpQzP4TbBXdxAA5Wn95Pb3vtt"
#define WIFI_SSID "Movistar_22670279"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "0091107058940"

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

// connect to wifi.
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
Serial.print("connecting");
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
Serial.print(".");
delay(500);
}
Serial.println();
Serial.print("connected: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
Firebase.set("LED_STATUS",0);
}

int n = 0;

void loop() {
// set value
n=Firebase.getInt("LED_STATUS");
// handle error
if (n==1) {
Serial.print("LED is ON");
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
Serial.println(Firebase.error());
return;
delay(100);
}
else{
Serial.print("LED is OFF");
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your firebase rules and enable it to read and write for testing.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to use the Firebase framework? That's a lot of includes and libraries and calls just to blink an LED. Most ESP8266 boards (I'm most familiar with the NodeMCU 1.0) can run the Blink example almost unmodified. You might have to change the LED pin.

NodeMCUs are designed to be programmed in Lua, but I teach an intro programming class with them using the Arduino IDE and C, and they work just fine. I suspect yours might, too.

Comment: they can run Blink, but the goal is to read a state from database

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I may not explain it well, the idea is turn on a LED through the Internet with a database based on firebase